# Div absolute position script - onkeyup even won't register

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a simple movement script with the arrow keys, however I'm having a weird behavior:

-If I press right for to long the circle goes crazy fast to the right

-If I do short presses the script works as intended

-I'm assuming pressing right for long is updating the function and making it update exponentially

-I still don't know why the onkeyup even stops registering after a long press.

the code is:

```
var circle = document.createElement("div");
     circle.style.borderRadius = "50%";
     circle.style.width = "100px";
     circle.style.height = "100px";
     circle.style.position = "absolute";
     circle.style.backgroundColor = "#99CC00";
     circle.id = "green_circle";
     document.body.appendChild(circle);

var greenCircle = document.getElementById("green_circle");

//Movement Interval:
var xPosition = 1
function rightMovement(){
    circle.style.left = (xPosition + "px");
    xPosition++;
    console.log("xPosition is: "+xPosition);
}
//Interval Initializers and stoppers -
function moveRight(){
    startRight = setInterval(rightMovement,1);
}  

function stopMovingRight(){
    clearInterval(startRight);
    console.log("onkeyup stop register")
}

//Event Keybinding
document.onkeydown = function(){
    var r = event.keyIdentifier;
    if(r == "Right"){
    moveRight();
    }
}

document.onkeyup = function(){
    var i = event.keyIdentifier;
    if(i == "Right"){
        stopMovingRight();
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

[I have js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etnos/DuyKr/)

Comment: If you take a careful look at your script, you'll notice, that every keydown will add a new interval...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When key is held down, your code starts multiple intervals. Use a boolean to check whether the circle is already moving or not.

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/DuyKr/1/)

```
moving=false;
function moveRight(){
  if(!moving){ //Start an interval only if there is none active
    startRight = setInterval(rightMovement,1);
    moving=true;
   }
}

document.onkeyup = function(){
 var i = event.keyIdentifier;
  if(i == "Right"){
    stopMovingRight();
    moving=false; // interval deactivated, start upon next keydown
    console.log(i);
 }
}
```

Comment: Ohh my that was pretty obvious, now I feel dumb hehe, Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Your method `moveRight()` is fired numerous times. This is because the `onkeydown` event is triggered multiple times when a key is held down. You can fix this by setting a flag that the key is down so `moveRight()` doesn't fire multiple times.

Every time `moveRight()` is called, an interval is set. I would also recommend initializing the `startRight` variable in the top of your script to make sure you won't get any errors. Like so:

```
var startRight = null;
```